# Aspnet Core DI + EF: "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

This is related to the following, but it is not exactly the same:
[EF. The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217906/ef-the-connection-was-not-closed-the-connections-current-state-is-connecting)

I understand this error can be the result of a race condition when dealing with DbContext.

Here is a simplified example of what was causing me problems, and my solution to fix it.  I just don't quite understand why my solution works:

Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("ConnString"));

// This will cause the "Connection was not closed..." error.
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SomeBackgroundService>(provider => 
    new SomeBackgroundService(provider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>());

// Instead, I instantiate the DbContext here instead of letting DI do it
// and this eliminates the error.
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, SomeBackgroundService(provider =>
    new SomeBackgroundService(new MyDbContext(
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseSqlServer("ConnString").Options));
```

Inside of my `SomeBackgroundService` I execute some asynchronous queries, while at the same time other queries are being executed inside controller methods.

However, that being the case, shouldn't using `provider.GetRequiredService<T>` instantiate a new DbContext in the same way?

Comment: You should never use a singleton in conjunction with a `DbContext`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I guess my question was more along the lines of, even if I _do_ have a singleton, I figured provider.GetRequiredService<T> would create an instance of DbContext to be injected into my singleton class?

Comment: Yes, which effectively makes that `DbContext` also a singleton. Now, if you try to use that across HTTP requests, it will explode.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Forgive me though, I'm still a little confused.  The `IHostedService` that uses the DbContext is a background task, so my thought is that the background task is not really being "accessed" across HTTP requests, just running in the background.  Are you saying that `provider.GetRequiredService<T>` used within the context of registering a singleton will not actually create a DbContext instance, but fetch an existing DbContext registered with the DI container -- which would be based on `services.AddDbcontext<T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation has examples on how to use scoped services within a hostes service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task.

TL;DR You inject the `IServiceProvider` (which is always available) into your IHostedService implementation, then create a scope per invocation and resolve the DbContext from there.

Comment: Thank you David, I believe that makes sense to me now. So am I right to say that  `services.AddDbContext<T>` registers the DbContext as a scoped service?  I will give this a shot, thanks again!